# Visual Basic String variable alternative

Tags: variables, text, integer, long-integer

I am currently having the problem that the string variable in visual basic is too small for my needs. It can only hold like 2 million chars. But My script is sorting a list of IPs. In each list there are like 10 - 100 Million IP's. I get a error as the variable is too small. Is there any alternative to string? (It can't be Long as its alphanumeric)
The Error i get can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think you can't have a string greater than 2Mb?

Comment: Read it somewhere that it doesnt support more than 4million bits

Comment: Well, 4million bits is closer to 512Kb, But I believe the main limiting factor on string length is the amount of memory available, and the CPU architecture; but without showing any of your code, it's going to be virtually impossible to make worthwhile suggestions

Comment: What version of VB are you using? The max length of a string in a Win32 app is close to 2GB. Posting an error dialog is meaningless. Your code must be *here*, in your question, not off-site. Asking us to go somewhere else to look at your code and then return here to answer is rather inconsiderate, and the site guidelines require all questions to be self-contained (all relevant information must be in the question itself). Remove the image, and replace it with your code - you can quote just the "unhandled exception" message **in text** in your post.

Comment: I have actually found the problem. You both were right. Its not the string type. The problem was my IP list contained a line break at the end causing my script to think there's another IP listed which isnt there. So it crashed. But thanks to you both for helping me.